# Create custom field inside OptionsetField in Silverstripe CMS 3.1

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I want to choose the type of my calendar events from some predefined values but also, create a new (custom) type if it's not listed.

So i have created the field in $db like so:
'Type' => 'Varchar',
'EventCustomType' => 'Varchar'

Then, in the getCMSFields() i have:

```
$f->addFieldsToTab("Root.Main", $eventType = new OptionsetField(
            'Type',
            _t('CalendarEvent.EVENTTYPE','Type'),
            array (
                'music'  => _t('CalendarEvent.MUSIC','Music'),
                'sport'  => _t('CalendarEvent.SPORT','Sport'),
                'drama'  => _t('CalendarEvent.DRAMA','Drama'),
                'custom' => TextField::create('EventCustomType','Event type')
            )
        )
    );
```

[image]

The problem is that i don't know how to insert the label "Custom" before the Textareafield and style them in the same line.

Also, i'm not sure if i need a second field for the custom one. Can i insert the custom value inside "Type" field or validate it ?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by having a separate field for "EventCustomType" and then using [Display Logic](https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic) to show it with something like...

```
$eventType = OptionsetField::create(
    'Type',
    _t('CalendarEvent.EVENTTYPE','Type'),
    array (
    'music'  => _t('CalendarEvent.MUSIC','Music'),
    'sport'  => _t('CalendarEvent.SPORT','Sport'),
    'drama'  => _t('CalendarEvent.DRAMA','Drama'),
    'custom' => _t('CalendarEvent.CUSTOM','Custom'),
    )
);

$fEventCustomType = TextField::create('EventCustomType','Event type')
    ->displayIf('Type')->isEqualTo('custom');

$f->addFieldsToTab("Root.Main", array($eventType,$fEventCustomType));
```

As an alternative if you wanted to rescue [This module](https://github.com/helpfulrobot/leapfrognz-alternative-field) then you could create this to save into one field as it is designed to do as you are asking... but it is with an error (last time I tried) so it is refernce only for now.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i have figured it out with separate fields:

```
    $eventType = OptionsetField::create(
        'Type',
        _t('CalendarEvent.EVENTTYPE','Type'),
        array (
        'music'  => _t('CalendarEvent.MUSIC','Music'),
        'sport'  => _t('CalendarEvent.SPORT','Sport'),
        'drama'  => _t('CalendarEvent.DRAMA','Drama'),
        'custom' => _t('CalendarEvent.CUSTOM','Custom'),
        )
    );

    $customEventType = TextField::create('EventCustomType','Custom type');

    $f->addFieldsToTab("Root.Main", array($eventType,$customEventType));
```

and jQuery:

```
$('#Root_Main').entwine({
    onmatch: function(){
        var $tab = this.closest('.tab');
        var $eventType = $tab.find('ul.eventType');
        var $customType = $tab.find('.customEventType').hide();

        if($eventType.find('input:checked').val() == 'custom'){
            $customType.show();
        }

        $eventType.find('input').change(function(){
            if($(this).val() == 'custom'){
                $customType.show();
            }else{
                $customType.hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Out of interest, how come display logic wasn't useful?

Comment: i couldn't install it via composer: Problem 1
    - Installation request for webbuilders-group/silverstripe-display-logic-extras ^0.1.0 -> satisfiable by webbuilders-group/silverstripe-display-logic-extras[0.1.0].
    - Conclusion: remove silverstripe/framework 3.1.18
    - Conclusion: don't install silverstripe/framework 3.1.18
    - webbuilders-group/silverstripe-display-logic-extras 0.1.0 requires silverstripe/framework ^3.2 -> satisfiable by silverstripe/framework[3.2.x-dev, 3.3.x-dev, 3.4.x-dev, ...].
... 4 more lines. And the other plugin gave me some erros(no update since 3 years)

Comment: Oh dear, I've found it much easier, I don't see a refernce to the webbuilders-group in https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic/blob/master/composer.json I think you might have choosen the wrong thing to include.  The webbuilders-group is an extension of the unclecheese one

Comment: yes. you are right. but, i think it requires ss 3.2 from it's composer.json:   "require":
    {
        "silverstripe/framework": "^3.2"
    },   so i am using 3.1.18 :(